# Android NavigationBarColor doesn't change to black (only to black)

Tags: android, styles, navigationbar

I debug on OnePlus 5t. It's standart navigation bar color is white. I want to change it to black.
So I created new styles file in values-v21 and added item "navigationBarColor":

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">#000000</item>
```

It didn't work. The color was still white. But here goes the funny thing:
I changed the color to #000001:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">#000001</item>
```

And it worked. The color changed to very-very dark blue.
Can someone tell me what's going on?
P.S @color/darkBlack didn't work too.

Comment: Do you use ColorDrawable with black color somewhere in your code? Android caches ColorDrawable , and if you change the ColorDrawable in one place, it will change wherever that ColorDrawable is used.

Comment: No, I don't use ColorDrawable

Comment: Same issue on Motoroga g5 plus. I am not able to change it to pure black #000. (Same code works in emulator though)